# Filter by freq dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I´m trying to filter a dataframe by the frequency of an observation appears, I have a dataframe with 70000 rows. This some part of it.

[image]

I need to filtering for example if in the colum inst_nombre_institucion there are 4 of the same, I will take that rows.

Comment: From the answer there, `df[ave(1:nrow(df), df$inst_nombre_institucion, FUN = length) == 4, ]`

Comment: Thank´s Frank, that´s exactly what I need!